# Adding and removing items from Windows 11 Right click (new) menu

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-11

I have Windows 11, and I have uninstalled, Paint, Paint3d, and notepad application and don't want to reinstall them

[image]

1. How to remove the New -> bitmap image? There's no `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bmp\ShellNew]` in the Registry Editor.
2. How to add "new -> text document"? I have tried creating a `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew]` [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193852/how-can-i-add-item-in-desktop-menu-new-file-right-click-on-desktop), nothing worked.

Comment: [Easy Context Menu](https://www.sordum.org/7615/easy-context-menu-v1-6/) might help.

Comment: @harrymc just checked, it doesn't help, it doesn't list the bitmap so I can remove it, nor I can see an option to add "create a new text document"

Comment: I'm not sure that the bitmap entry can be removed. But it's very strange that you don't have an entry for text document. Have you uninstalled notepad?

Comment: @harrymc yes I have uninstalled notepad, and that caused the text document entry to be deleted. I reinstalled notepad and the entry is still gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on your problems.

**New > Bitmap image**

I managed to get rid of the entry "Bitmap image", but that required
uninstalling Paint from *Settings > Apps > Installed apps*.
Reboot was required for removing it from the context menu.

You need to decide if you wish to uninstall Microsoft Paint or to suffer
"Bitmap image" in the New menu.

**New > Text document**

I have repeated your experience by uninstalling the notepad app,
so that the "Text document" entry was removed from the New menu.

To return the entry, I needed to install `notepad` from the
Microsoft Store.
Reboot is required for it to take effect.